# Is it possible to read a preflight requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, cors, preflight

When we send non-[simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) to another domain, the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is being send first by the browser. Is it possible to somehow read the body or headers of preflight request responses in javascript?

For example:

```
fetch('example.com', { method: "DELETE" }).then(handler)
```

Will trigger a preflight request and if it succeeds, the "handler" function will be able to read a response for our main request. But is there any way to access the preflight request's response?

Comment: I don't think you could access the response to the `OPTIONS` request sent by the browser but you could send an `OPTIONS` request yourself.

Comment: No, there isn’t any way for you to read the preflight response programatically from your frontend JavaScript code. There’s no API in browsers which exposes the preflight response to frontend JavaScript code — neither the response headers, nor the response body, nor even the response status code.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the [fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch), my understanding of the request access is the preflight request will be returned if it had an error, otherwise, the main request will be returned (error or not) and the preflight will go inaccessible. <s>However, I wasn't able to test this, and the specification wasn't the clearest for understanding the behavior of the function.</s>

**Edit:**
I did some testing with https://test-cors.org, and found that I was wrong. Whenever the CORS request fails, all that you can get is the error object. If the request succeeds, all you get is the final response. The automated preflight request is completely hidden from JS, so as @Titus said in a comment, the only way to get the preflight response is to manually configure and send an `OPTIONS` request.